# How to get Json result in to the table using angularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve whole table in mvc5 using angularJS. 
Data in Json result is being displayed but not in the table as I wanted.

I'm using mvc5 and angularjs(1.x) to retrive the data from sql server

Here's the Data Access Layer code:

```
public List<Employee> ShowAllEmployee()
        {
            List<Employee> prdList = userdb.Employees.ToList();
            return prdList;
        }
```

Here's the HomeController method:

```
 public JsonResult AllEmployee()
        {
            repo = new Employee_DAL.EmpRepo();
            var hotList = repo.ShowAllEmployee();
            List<Models.Employee> mList = new List<Models.Employee>();
            foreach (var hotl in hotList)
            {
                Models.Employee hotLocal = new Models.Employee();
                hotLocal.EmployeeId = hotl.EmployeeId;
                hotLocal.FirstName = hotl.FirstName;
                hotLocal.LastName = hotl.LastName;
                hotLocal.Designation = hotl.Designation;
                //hotLocal.Description = hotl.Description;
                hotLocal.Country = hotl.Country;
                hotLocal.Gender = hotl.Gender;
                //hotLocal.Rating = hotl.Rating;
                //hotLocal.Email = hotl.Email;
                mList.Add(hotLocal);
            }
            return Json(mList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here's the script ( angular) code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyModule', []);
myApp.controller('DBcontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Home/AllEmployee') // added an '/' along with deleting Controller portion
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.students = response.data
        })
})
```

Here's my view(cshtml):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Customs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Customs/Scripts.js"></script>
    <title>AllEmployee</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="DBcontroller">

        <table class="table-bordered">

            <tr>

                <th>Emp No</th>

                <th>First Name</th>

                <th>Last Name</th>

                <th>Designation</th>

                <th>Country</th>

                <th>Gender</th>

            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="e in students" @*ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'"*@>

                <td>{{e.EmployeeId}}</td>

                <td>{{e.FirstName}}</td>

                <td>{{e.LastName}}</td>

                <td>{{e.Designation}}</td>

                <td>{{e.Country}}</td>

                <td>{{e.Gender}}</td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

I expect the jsonresult to be displayed in a table. Not directly like this in the browser.[Screenshot of my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aybaM.jpg)

[image]